# The Apple Developer Program License Agreement has been updated

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I got a mail from apple "This certificate will no longer be valid in 30 days. To create a new certificate, visit Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles in your account".I login into the developer site ,it shows message "The Apple Developer Program License Agreement has been updated".My doubt is whether i need to resubmit my app already in appstore? Whether i need to pay any amount for updating licence agreement.My app use push notification service,Please give advice

Comment: if licence is expires you need to renew ,else no need

Comment: No need to update the app or submit new app to store, you just need to accept the agreement, also if your account is expiring then you need to renew the account, otherwise apps won't be listed on app store if your account expires

Comment: my app use pushnotification,whether it work or not

Comment: @priya.vr It doesn't matter whether your app uses push or not. Renewing apple program or accepting updated agreement doesn't mean that you have to update the app.

Comment: But i receive the mail "This certificate will no longer be valid in 30 days. To create a new certificate, visit Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles in your account" ,thats why i am asking my pushnotification will work or not

Comment: Please read this https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal/

Answer (score 0):

the final logic for apple is:

"user have bought app, do not disrupt in any weay." :)

(different things for push notifications. but is another story. Your server will have invalid credentials...)